# How do I migrate MySQL to PostgreSQL in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I tried to migrate my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL.
Whenever I migrated I got this error, I'm new to PostgreSQL, I wish somebody have an idea

[image: errror message]
[image: this is my schema]

Comment: Do you mean sqlite or mysql? You said, and tagged, sqlite; but things like "ENGINE=InnoDB" suggests MySQL. ...though the data types look like sqlite... are you going from sqlite to mysql (not postgres)?

Comment: im sorry  i meant mysql2 to postgresql.. ill edit it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `:options` for your `create_table` call are MySQL-specific so you can just drop them:

```
create_table :versions do |t|
  #...
end
```

There are a couple other things you might want to change as well:

1. `t.string` without a `:limit` is equivalent to `t.text` with PostgreSQL. You might want to add a `:limit` to those if you're assuming that MySQL's default size limit on `varchar` columns (if any) will be applied. Or you could change it to `t.text` to be more explicit that you want an arbitrarily sized column.
2. There is no `:limit` option for `t.text` in PostgreSQL so you should drop that to avoid confusion.
3. Depending what your `object` column really is, you might want to migrate that to `jsonb`. For example, if you're using `serialize :object` in your model then it would be better off as `jsonb` without serializing it to YAML like `serialize` does.
4. `t.string` with a `:limit` (i.e. `varchar(n)` in the database) is actually slightly more expensive than `t.string` without a `:limit` (which is really just `t.text` with a different name). If you don't have a strict need for that `limit: 191` then you might want to drop it and let `item_type` without a strict size limit. You don't have to drop the `:limit` but it doesn't serve much purpose with PostgreSQL.